# Error using VideoReader in matlab - gstreamer problem

Tags: plugins, matlab, gstreamer

I'm trying to use VideoReader in MATLAB on an Ubuntu system and get the following error:

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)    
(MATLAB:4573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
```

2. When I try the solution to set `LD_PRELOAD` using `LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" matlab`

   I get this error:

   ```
   MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
   libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
   libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
   libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
   libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
   libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
   libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
   libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
   libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)

   (MATLAB:803): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 
   Trying to dispose element tmwplaybin, but it is in READY instead of the NULL state.
   You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
   dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
   This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
   application or some element.
   ```
3. A related issue is that when I try to use Parole Media Player to open a video I also get an error:

   ```
   GStreamer backend error
   Could not initialise Xv output
   ```
4. I read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1246784) and now I have the error in step 2

What can I do to fix this?