# What causes this GStreamer warning when closing MATLAB?

Tags: command-line, matlab, gstreamer

After working in MATLAB and with an Editor window still open, I unmaximized the main window and clicked the X to close it. What caused these warnings output in Terminal? Should I care?

(Hours beforehand, I tried opening a new terminal window, hence those initial ^N's ...)

```
sony@SonyVaioWhite:~$ matlab
^N^[^N (MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING
**: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
(MATLAB:2996): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5)
```

Comment: Probably the same thing as https://askubuntu.com/q/976415/158442 (which as no answer posted)

Comment: In my case this warning occurred while closing the software, whereas for these others their warnings or errors occurred through different actions. I have not combed through the messages to see if they are identical, though one user's appears different: It seems better to ignore the warning at this point, since I do not see that it affects me ...